# How to map a single PostGIS function to multiple Spatialite functions with GeoAlchemy2

Tags: postgis, spatialite, geoalchemy, sqlalchemy

In PostGIS we have `ST_Affine(geom, a, b, d, e, xoff, yoff)` but in Spatialite this functionality is split across 2 functions: `ATM_Transform( geom , affine_matrix )`, and `ATM_Create(a, b, d, e, xoff, yoff)`. How would I go about doing something similar to [this](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/test_specific_compilation.html#sphx-glr-gallery-test-specific-compilation-py) using GeoAlchemy2? As far as I can tell, I can't split up and compile individually the `compiled = compiler.process(element.clauses, **kw)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question answered here https://github.com/geoalchemy/geoalchemy2/issues/377

```
def _compile_affine_sqlite(element, compiler, **kw):
    """Compile the element for the SQLite dialect."""
    compiled = compiler.process(element.clauses, **kw)
    affine_params = list(element.clauses)

    element.identifier = "ATM_Transform"

    atm_create_clause = func.ATM_Create(*[i.value for i in affine_params[1:]])
    element.clauses.clauses = element.clauses.clauses[:1] + [atm_create_clause]
    atm_create_compiled = compiler.process(element.clauses, **kw)
    return '{}({})'.format(element.identifier, atm_create_compiled)

compiles(functions.ST_Affine, 'sqlite')(_compile_affine_sqlite)
```